# How to rotate the object based on OBJ center point in Three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want flip(rotate)  based on the center of the obj using thee js, I have attachec screen shot please refer [Clieck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JjAl.png), I have used below three js code, Please any one help me

```
object.opacity     = 2; 
object.castShadow = true;
object.receiveShadow = false;
var anglex="+";
var angley="-";
var angle=180; 
object.rotation.y  =  angle*(Math.PI/180); 
object.mirroredLoop  = true;
object.castShadow  = true;
object.receiveShadow  = true;
object.name = 'model_'+file;        
object.key  = object_keyid;   
scene.add( object );
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848863/threejs-how-to-rotate-around-objects-own-center-instead-of-world-center/

Comment: That is not work

Comment: (1) Please re-read the post WestLangley provided. Your object will always rotate about its own center. If you meant to say that you want to rotate your object about a _different_ point, [this post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812861/three-js-pivot-point/42866733). (2) Your picture does not do a good job of conveying what you want. To get the best answers, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can see what you're seeing, and provide code which fits into your framework.