# How to rotate a ThreeJS Object3D object around its end?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to rotate an Object3D object about its end? I found my object's center with `const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.object)` to determine the center. Would rotating at a point mean translating the object to one point, rotate, then translate back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three JS Pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812861/three-js-pivot-point)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to rotate an Object3D object about its end?

Yes. By default, Object3D rotates about its center, but it's possible to change rotation point by "wrapping" object in parent (Object3D) and setting position for parent (this will be also a rotation point):

```
function changeRotationPoint(obj, scene, position) {
  // create parent and add it to scene
  const parent = new THREE.Object3D();

  parent.add(obj);
  if (obj.parent) {
    obj.parent.add(parent);
  } else {
    // add to THREE scene if obj doesn't have a
    // parent
    scene.add(parent);
  }

  // position for rotation, 
  // for example (put your data): { x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0 }
  parent.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);

  // correct position of obj, so only rotation point
  // will be changed
  const x = obj.position.x - position.x,
  const y = obj.position.y - position.y,
  const z = obj.position.z - position.z
  obj.position.set(x, y, z);
}

// call function
changeRotationPoint(this.object, scene, { x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0 });

// rotate this.object
this.object.parent.rotation.set(0.1, 0.2, 0.3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and example! How would we get the endpoint of our object if we want to rotate around there? From your example, it seems that we need to know the exact point we want to rotate at.

Comment: @HannahBernal yes, you're right, we need to know desired rotating point, or calculate if it's possible.

Comment: Hm, ok that makes sense! Just making sure, would `obj.position` reference the center of the object? Also, I don't think your code works if an object is already a child of another object since it detaches from the original parent and resets the scale

Comment: `obj.position reference the center of the object? ` object position by default will be 0, 0, 0, and it will rotate (by default) around its center. But you can find the center using box3d. `Also, I don't think your code works if an object is already a child of another object since it detaches from the original parent and resets the scale` - it works fine and it doesn't impact any of other object property, until you have changed it. Using parent for changing rotation point works in all cases, translation - only for objects with geometry. Check here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1364